# Drupal 7 form missing from $form object during Ajax callback function

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm using this [example code](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/function/ajax_example_add_more/7.x-1.x) to create a 'add another field' to my custom Form. The form itself is quite big and showing a full example here isn't possible.

The problem I'm having is that when I hit my callback button to 'add another field' the `$form` variable is missing most of the form I wish to utilise. My form is an admin area only form, but using the above example works fine in my implementation as POC.

The form utilises vertical_tabs but I have also tried without. I have a lot of validation around this form and in essence it's being built of a yaml file but I can't work out why the form elements are missing during the ajax callback. `$form_state` contains all the values submitted by the form including the missing data from `$form`.

I had assumptions that `#tree` was the issue but, I have this set to `TRUE` from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anybody wants to know the issue was I was trying to obtain a value from `arg()` and this was different for the ajax callback funtion. So in my `hook_form` function I set the following:

```
  // This is needed for the ajax callback
  if (arg(1) != 'ajax') {
    // We need to set the variable before we load the form.
    $form_state['value'] = arg(3);
    $key = arg(3);
  }
  else {
    // Ajax callback can now reference correct key.
    $key = $form_state['value'];
  }
```

This allowed me to obtain the correct value during the ajax callback function.

Comment: Yes, for most Ajax calls, they hit `system/ajax` path, so checking `arg()` won't result in much.